# I Can only ping IP address and website with domain but browse, telnet etc.. don't work?

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns, dhcp

[screenshot/network-settings1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8uJI.png)
[screenshot/network-settings2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGPuL.png)

I have a PC running Ubuntu 18.04.
I don't have any proxy settings.

`ifconfig` shows this:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:15:5d:6d:75:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 59988  bytes 17593743 (17.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10133  bytes 1763200 (1.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.109.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
    ether 00:15:5d:6d:75:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 43741  bytes 4775417 (4.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6999  bytes 601083 (601.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5654  bytes 555802 (555.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5654  bytes 555802 (555.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

eth1 is for internet and receives the correct DHCP addresses from ISP. I can ping from this computer the DNS servers at my ISP, I can ping www.google.com and any other sites

```
root@server:~# ping www.facebook.com
PING star-mini.c10r.facebook.com (31.13.84.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from edge-star-mini-shv-01-vie1.facebook.com (31.13.84.36): icmp_seq=22 ttl=57 time=8.81 ms
```

and nslookup works to, but I can't browse them and I also can't connect with telnet to any of them and I don't know the reason.

Copied from comment below, so I could apply formatting:

@waltinator yes and this ist the output:

```
ip route 
default via 192.168.109.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 20100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1000
192.168.109.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.109.109 metric 100
```

Comment: Could you please run `sudo ifconfig` and post back the info?

Comment: Does `ip route ` show a "`default`" route?

Comment: @jwcooper I have added the info thank you for your response to the question 

Comment: @waltinator yes and this ist the output: `ip route`
default via 192.168.109.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.109.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.109.109 metric 100
thank you for your response to the question 

Comment: Nothing jumps out from ifconfig, How are you connected to the internet? Are you behind a router? If so, is there another machine you can plug in using the same cable and router port to make sure it isnt a router setting?

Comment: @jwcooper its a virtual mashin and eth1 is connected to wifi of my pc via virtual ethernet cable and it received the correct DHCP addresses from ISP

Comment: Alright, so we are on to something now. I'm guessing that the host machine (the one running vmware or virtualbox or whatever) is able to browse successfully? If so, please post your virtual machine network settings.

Comment: @jwcooper My windows10 computer via Wi-Fi connected to internet can browse successfully but the ubuntu virtual machine witch has the same connection and correct IP address  can’t but only able to ping ips and domains.
With network setting I don’t know what you exactly mean but etc/network/interfaces is empty there is just
auto lo and iface lo inet loopback.
but I noticed that in ubuntu the ping of domains sometimes works and sometimes not and sometimes takes too long

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Post a screenshot of the virtual machine config settings. Specifically, the part where you setup the network. This is the GUI you use to assign the number of processors and HDD size when you first create the virtual machine. If you dont want to post a screenshot, you can just try one of the other network options for the VM (should only be like three) and try restarting it and using the browser again. Sounds like you chose the option to assign the VM its own IP. Try the one where it shares an IP with the host.

Comment: @jwcooper It becames better! the ping takes not too long any more after I have added a new network adapter thanks a lot for your guidance but its still not able to browse the websites although i can ping them successfully with 0% packet loss
and I have also added the screenshots but I think they seem not so usefull

Comment: Almost there it seems. What is the message you get when trying to browse to the sites? It sounds like maybe your DNS isnt set? Can you go to your network settings in Ubuntu and make your DNS 8.8.8.8. Then restart and try to access the sites again. Try a couple different sites including Google. Can you try a wired connection instead of wireless? Also, maybe remove the network adapter you arent using in the settings.

Comment: @jwcooper It finally worked after I did it..! I would like to thank you again for your wonderful guidance 

Comment: Cool man. I'm going to make that an answer. Please accept it if you get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was eventually corrected by first changing the VM network config to share the host machines IP address and then adding 8.8.8.8 as the DNS address. If anyone else is having a similar problem, it may be worth reading through the comments to try some of the other troubleshooting steps as well.